# Double integral of $\arctan(x + y)$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I would like to find

$\int_a^b\int_a^b\arctan(x+y)dydx$

I can "simplify" the integration down to

$\int_a^b ((x+b)\arctan(x+b)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+(x+b)^2) - (x+a)\arctan(x+a)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+(x+a)^2))dx$

...but I would not know what to do from there.

Comment: Maybe try partial integration?

Comment: I end up with another integral that's difficult to solve. Is there a way that does not involve brute force?

Comment: Why not using the coordinate trafo $x+y=R$ and $x-y=r$. The Jacobian should be $1/2$.. This should really simplify matters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change coordinates: $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$.  Jacobian = $1/2$.  Then the integral is

$$\int_{-(b-a)}^{b-a} dv \, \int_{2 a}^{2 b} du \, \arctan{u} $$

The integral of arctan is easy using integration by parts:

$$\int du \, \arctan{u} = u \arctan{u} - \frac12 \log{(1+u^2)} +C$$

Hopefully you can take it from there.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not familiar with coordinate transformations using a Jacobian. I tried looking it up, but they used x and y in terms of u and v instead of u = x + y and v = x - y here; could you clarify this for me?

Comment: @user234189: you can solve for $x$ and $y$ from $u$ and $v$, right?

Comment: @Ron Gordon: Yes, but how do you know to use v = x - y or y = -(u - v)/2?

Comment: @user234189: that is just experience.  You are integrating over a function of $x+y$, so it makes sense to explore this transformation.

Comment: @Ron Gordon: Okay, thank you!